# Android Emulator won't start up in windows 8.1

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I've been using android emulator in my windows 7 32 bit. It was slow but it worked. I did a fresh install of windows 8 64 bit and now emulator won't start up. It runs and then disappears without any trace.

I checked event viewer and it showed this error

```
Faulting application name: emulator-arm.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5578d73a
Faulting module name: ig4icd32.dll, version: 8.15.10.2104, time stamp: 0x4bb3c8e9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00519b7c
Faulting process id: 0x8bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0aba512ba012d
Faulting application path: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator-arm.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig4icd32.dll
Report Id: 52412f1e-1798-11e5-826f-6cadef12cfb7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. This solution will probably work for Intel G41 express chipset. Any problem related to `ig4icd32.dll` is related to graphics drivers. For most of the case, the solution is to upgrade graphics driver.

But I was using the latest graphics driver which is version `8.15.10.2702`. I was out of option. So just to check, I downgraded to version `8.15.10.1883` which is the version provided in Intel website. It solved the error. I can use the emulator again.